# Swift JSON variable return nil in other method

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have a problem with JSON.
I wrote a class called Book.swift

```
class Book {

var id: Int?
var name: String?
var author: String?
var translator: String?
var publisher: String?
var genre: String?
var yop: String?
var pageTotal: String?
var description: String?


var cover_url: String?

}
```

in my ViewController I called JSON with Alamofire and SwiftyJSON

```
class BookSingleController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

var book  = Book()

func URLRequest(url:String) {



        let URLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: url)!)
        URLRequest.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReturnCacheDataElseLoad


        UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true

        Alamofire.request(.GET, url)
            .validate()
            .responseJSON { response in


                switch response.result {
                case .Success:
                    if let jsonData = response.result.value {

                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

                            let json = JSON(jsonData)


                            if let item = json["books"].array {


                                self.book = Book()

                                self.book.name = item[0]["title"].string
                                self.book.author = item[0]["author"]["name"].string
                                self.book.translator = item[0]["translator"]["name"].string
                                self.book.cover_url = item[0]["cover_url"].string
                                self.book.yop = item[0]["year_of_publish"].string
                                self.book.genre = item[0]["genres"].string
                                self.book.pageTotal = item[0]["number_of_page"].string
                                self.book.publisher = item[0]["publisher"].string
                                self.book.description = item[0]["description"].string


                            }

                            return

                        })
                        self.tableRefresh()
                        UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false

                    }
                case .Failure(let error):
                    UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
                    print(error)
                }

        }
}
```

I have another method to assign book variable to tableView cell's label

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

cell.nameLabel.text = self.book.name

return cell
}
```

but self.book.name return nil in tableView method.can you guys tell me where is my mistake please? thanks

**EDIT:**
put self.tableView.reloadData() in dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue() but still return nil

```
func tableRefresh()
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        self.tabelView.reloadData()
    })
}
```

Comment: Are `id`, `name`, `author`, `publisher`, `pageTotal`, and `genre` really optional on a book? I would have thought that every book would have an id and title? Also, is `pageTotal` not an `Int`? Does it make sense to store it as a `String`? Finally, would it not be better to use a `struct` here instead of a class?

Comment: @Fogmeister you think it must be like this: var id: Int!
var name: String!

Comment: No, just Int and String

Comment: many thanks @Fogmeister. big help.

Comment: I frogot alarmofire back with main thread @Fogmeister his comment is right

Comment: @Fogmeister when I try to use var id : Int, xcode show me an error. I have to set default value like this. var id : Int = 0. is this better way than var id = Int()?